# Cross-platform C/C++ code to get details on connected iDevices?

Tags: c++, iphone, c, cross-platform, device-detection

I'm working a cross-platform tool written in C++ that will have the ability to detect the deviceid (i.e. `iPhone7,1`) and iOS version (i.e. `8.1.2`) of connected devices, similar to how many jailbreak utilities do.

After looking around, I haven't been able to find a solution that is cross-platform (OSX and Windows, and maybe even Linux) and isn't a large library (libimobiledevice), and I know this can be done.

Does anyone have any insight on how to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as c/c++ there is c and there is c++.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to write an application that does something like what you're trying to do (get information about an IDevice), and the best thing I have found is libimobiledevice.

For Mac OS X, you can use the `system_profiler` command, and have it dump the output as xml, then parse it to find deviceid, and possibly IOS version. However, as I said, I think libimobiledevice is your best bet.